# What is the average Leg-to-Foot Length/Width Ratio?

Tags: anatomy, human-anatomy

I'm making a program that estimates a probable size (widest width and longest length) for a human's foot given the length and width of the leg to which it is attached. However, try as I might, **I can't seem to find the average foot-to-leg size ratio. Does anyone know this?** It would be even better if you have different ratios for males and females.

As a note, I *don't* want to know that this varies depending on certain circumstances, just a good average number that will let me generate people who aren't grossly out-of-proportion

Answer (score 3):

A brief study I conducted of my peers (10 people of varying genders, ages, and races, all about average body type) revealed a rather consistent foot-to-leg length ratio of 1:3 for males and females (variance is insignificant), and width of 2:3 for males and 1:2 for females.

Comment: Insignificant at a glance of after Chi-Squared with regards to the foot-leg ratio of males/females? How big was your sample?

Comment: @RoryM It was brief; sample of about 10 people ages 18 to 25. I didn't quite have the time to do an expansive study of peoples' legs since yesterday :P

Comment: poor effort - I'd have expected at least 100,000 samples in 24 hours!!  You might want to include that information in your answer to help future visitors from google etc =)